# Implicit differentiation with circle and tangent, finding gradient of tangent

Tags: calculus

[enter image description here][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySied.jpg. Also with the question, I’ve gotten to the point where dy/dx= (2x+6)/(2y-8) and not sure what to do after this. Thank you

Comment: Hi, you are requested not to post questions as pictures. Please type out the content of the link. Also, please write out, in full detail, how you arrived at the value of dy/dx that you state.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the derivative. Here is the elementary way to find the gradient.

The line with equation
$$mx -y -2= 0 \iff y = mx-2.$$
The gradient is $m$.
The curve is
$$x^2 + 6x+y^2-8y = 4.$$
By substitute $y$, we obtain
$$x^2 + 6x + (mx-2)^2 - 8(mx-2) = 4 $$
$$\iff x^2+6x + (mx^2-4mx+4)-8mx+16 = 4$$
$$\iff x^2(1+m) + x(6-4m-8m) + 16 = 0.$$
Because the line touches the circle, so the discriminant is equal to zero.
$$(6-12m)^2-4(1+m)(16) = 0 \iff 36(1+4m^2-4m)-64m-64 = 0$$
As a result
$$144m^2-208m -28 = 0 \iff 36m^2-52m - 7 = 0.$$
So the value of $m$ are
$$m_1 = \frac{52 + \sqrt{(52^2 + 4(7)(36)}}{72} = \frac{52 + \sqrt{3712}}{72}; \space m_2 = \frac{52 - \sqrt{3712}}{72}.$$